# How can I set the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE start path the first time a user uses my app?

Tags: android

I've seen a lot of questions regarding setting the start `Uri` for the `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` but all of those require a `Uri` that comes from having used that folder picker before.

What I want to do is send my users directly to the `Download` folder when picking the folder but I do not know how to convert `/storage/emulated/0/Download` to a `Uri` that I can pass as an extra using `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`.

Is there a way to convert any file path to a `DocumentsContract` style `Uri`?

Edit: Just to be clear, I'm talking about the `uri` passed here:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        .setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
        )
        .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri)
```

Comment: For which Android version this should work?

Comment: Ideally Android 5+ but I really need it starting with Android 11.

Comment: Ok. `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` Start with removing that flag. You cannot grant anything here. In onActivityResult read/write access will be granted to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove that, but still need to figure out how to pass the `uri` for the downloads directory.

Comment: You know that on an Android 11 device the Download folder is not selectable anymore?

Comment: Well download was just an example really. Plus I'm going to allow users to use SAF also on older version of Android.

Comment: If you only want to open the downloads folder you can use the following

startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We manupulate INITIAL_URI of .createOpenDocumentTreeIntent().

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
    //String startDir = "Android";
    //String startDir = "Download"; // Not choosable on an Android 11 device
    //String startDir = "DCIM";
    //String startDir = "DCIM/Camera";  // replace "/", "%2F"
    String startDir = "DCIM%2FCamera";

    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

    String scheme = uri.toString();

    Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

    scheme += "%3A" + startDir;

    uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

    Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());

    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    return;
}
```

The logs will print something like:

```
INITIAL_URI scheme: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/root/primary
uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload
```

Comment: Your code is perfect, cheers for saving my weeks of struggle trying to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is:
for example, if i want the user to select MEDIA folder of WhatsApp

```
                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
                    val initial = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia")
                    i.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, initial)
                    startActivityForResult(i, SCOPED_REQUEST_WA)
```