# How to save Tempfile to External storage using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Tags: java, android, file, outputstream, android-external-storage

unable to save the zip file to external storage after picking a folder using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

I'm creating a project which creates and manipulate files and document, in that task I want to save that stuff in external storage but I can't do that with android developer documentation, so please explain additionally.

**I want to save this file**

```
/data/user/0/com.mobilix.docscanner/cache/abc.zip
```

**to**

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocument
```

what should I do?

here is my code,

**- code for picking a directory to save a file into.**

```
saveBinding.btnInternalStorage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);


                startActivityForResult(intent, PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
```

**- Code to be executed after selecting a directory,**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICKER_RESULT) {

                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String path = uri.getPath();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: uri -> " + uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: path -> " + path);

                    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(
                            uri,
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    );


                    new BgExecuter().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            FileManager.saveFile(PDFTools.this,selectedFile, Uri); //selectedFile is that file that is saved by default in the Temp directory
                        }
                    });
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(PDFTools.this, "dome thing happen great", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

method **saveFile**

```
public static void saveFile(Activity context, File selectedFile, Uri uri) {
        context.getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile));
            OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

            // get the content in bytes
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            try {
                byte bytes = (byte) bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray);
                if (bytes >= 0) {
                    bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, bytes);
                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I want to save this file` ? You want to make a copy?

Comment: Is there any reason why you won't let the user choose the filename (or use a suggested name you provide), as `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` would probably be better than `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for copying out a single zip file. And why do you use a convoluted route of try to create a URL from a File when your InputStream can be created direct from the file as `getCacheDir()` is private to your app and does not have any access restrictions for using a `File` object

Comment: i'm already use Uri = data.getdata();

Comment: @blackapps yes,i want to make a copy in external storage from cache folder.

Comment: As per my previous comment, it seems you are trying to write a "File" in to a "Directory" Object Uri without creating a file in the directory first, Get the user to select a "File" to save it to or create a file in the directory first

Comment: `PDFTools.this,selectedFile, Uri);` What is Uri? This will not compile. Use the uri obtained from DocumentFile.createFile().

Comment: @Andrew (1) i want to create a zip file in to app cache  directory for sharing to third party apps,and
(2) save it  in external storage where user select a path using ACTIOB_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Comment: To create the zip in the documents directory you don't need to request access for that directory, you just need to request a file Uri from the user, as you don't have code to handle filenames already existing in that directory by the name you would like to use and then have to handle if it is already used and the fact that the user wants to keep the existing file.

Comment: but zip file created by me(not user) and then I will save it in cache dir and after user want to save it in a selected path,I want to save it in that path but I can't save it.

Comment: Trying to save it to a "public" external location with a static name (without give the user a choice on the name) creates additional problems and code you need to do handle if that static name already exists (i.e. don't write the file unless the user confirms they want to overwrite the existing file), Much better to allow the user to choose the name or accept your suggestion.

Comment: ok, ok. in that case I enter and edit file name by the user in-app interface,so is it ok to go with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Asking for a file instead of directory to be nicer to the user and lessen overwriting issues.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

// Create a file with the requested MIME type.
intent.setType(mimeType);
// Suggest a filename
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "abc.zip");
// You can suggest a starting directory here see note about this later
//intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);
// OK, this is deprecated and user probably has set their own request code
startActivityForResult(intent, 601);



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (requestCode == 601 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
            // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
            // provided to this method as a parameter.
            // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
            Uri uri;
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                new BgExecuter().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
 // Now that the Uri returned is for a file not a directory, your exist "saveFile" method should work
                            copyFileOut(PDFTools.this, selectedFile, Uri);
//selectedFile is that file that is saved by default in the Temp directory
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }


private Boolean copyFileOut(Context context,File copyFile, Uri uri){

        BufferedInputStream bis;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        // Now read the file
        try{
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(copyFile);
            int originalSize = input.available();

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri));
            byte[] buf = new byte[originalSize];
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            bis.read(buf);
            do {
                bos.write(buf);
            } while (bis.read(buf) != -1);
            bis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (BuildConfig.LOG) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "copyFileOut:" + e);
            }
            // Notify User of fail
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Note for initial start directory see [How I set the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE start path the first time a user uses my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67509218/how-i-set-the-action-open-document-tree-start-path-the-first-time-a-user-uses-my)

Also note that in your "saveFile" method

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile));
```

could be replaced with

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
```

As you say that this file is in your Apps private Cache directory, so won't have any permissions problems.

Comment: Thanks,but file saves of 0B,what's wrong with this?

Comment: Updated to use a method I use as you did not have a while loop to read all the file

Comment: Note you could have solved it with the direction @blackapps was taking, but I personally think it is unnecessary to ask for a directory to save a single file in it. That approach would be better if you had multiple files to copy out of your cache Directory

Answer (score 0):

> > String path = uri.getPath();

No no no.

You got a nice uri. Use it.

Create a DocumentFile instance for this tree uri.

Then use DocumentFile.createFile().

Comment: `getPath` use seems to be for debug use only

Comment: use of **Uri.getPath();** I can't create a file at the destination, it's always throwing an exception.

Comment: DocumentFile.createFile(). Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception. why this exception throes?

Comment: Well show complete code in a new code block. Try to create the file in onActivityResult().