# Save file on Android public folder has started to fail

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my Android app the user creates PDF files, they are stored inside the app's private folder. Then I give them the possibility to save these files to public folders using this code:

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    File file = new File(filename);
    Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(myActivity,
            myActivity.getApplicationContext() .getPackageName() + ".provider",
            file);
    sharingIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, file.getName());
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.TXT_PDFREPORT_SHARE)));
```

This has been working perfectly for a long time until a couple of weeks ago. Since then, files are created in the selected folder (with the Chooser intent), but it's empty (the file always has 0 bytes).

I'm trying to find out if Android has changed anything related to this but I can not find it. Why this code is not working now? What should I change?

Comment: "This has been working perfectly for a long time" -- `EXTRA_STREAM` is [not documented to be used by `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT). Your `addFlags()` does not make sense in this circumstance, and the same goes for `createChooser()`. You are not using `startActivityForResult()` and using the `Uri` that you get back in `onActivityResult()`. Most of this code makes sense for `ACTION_SEND`. Perhaps you accidentally changed the action string in the `Intent`.

Comment: check out this Question of mine, may this be helpful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064340/how-to-save-tempfile-to-external-storage-using-action-open-document-tree

Comment: Thanks! @EAS your link has worked!

Comment: @Wonton if that question is helpful to you,please do upvote.

Comment: @EAS I've just done it.