# ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> / Does not create a PDF file / ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: java, android

I have a problem creating a PDF file with "ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT".
Creating the PDF file still works with "public void onActivityResult". However, "public void onActivityResult" has recently been depresated.

Now I tried to create the PDF file with "ActivityResultLauncher". A file (0 bytes) is created. I noticed that when creating the file, there is no jump to the try block (createDocument) (jumps to catch).
How can I process or request the request code with "ActivityResultLauncher"? Or am I completely wrong?

Example 1, code works.

Example 2, 0 bytes (jumps in catch, function "createDocument").

---

---

Example 1 (onActivityResult) works for me:

```
//OnStart()
Intent intentm = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
                intentm.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intentm.setType("application/pdf");
                intentm.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, dateiname1);
                startActivityForResult(intentm, WRITE_REQ);//depresated!!!!!!!!!!!!

___________________________________________________________________________________________

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = null;
            if (resultData != null) {

                //uri in String speichern um später irgendwo im Code "Speichern" zu können
                //Siehe Funktion "private void editDocument(Uri uri)"
                uri = resultData.getData();
                PfadNeu = uri.toString();
             }

           
            if (requestCode == WRITE_REQ) {
                createDocument(uri);//is working!!!!!!!!!!!!
            }

        }
    }

______________________________________________________________________________________________


private void createDocument(Uri uri) {

// create a new document

.....
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(500, 700, 1).create();

        // start a page

        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

 canvas.drawText(euroj, 283, 320, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurof, 283, 335, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euromaer, 283, 350, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euroa, 283, 365, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euromai, 283, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurojun, 283, 395, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurojul, 283, 410, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euroaug, 283, 425, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurosep, 283, 440, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurookt, 283, 455, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euronov, 283, 470, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurodez, 283, 485, paint);
        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);



        try {

            ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            document.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            Toast.makeText(WeitereTools.this,"PDF - Datei wurde erstellt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        document.close();

}


___________________________________________________________________________________________
___________________________________________________________________________________________

Example 2 (ActivityResultLauncher) not works:

//OnStart()
 Intent intentm = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
                intentm.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intentm.setType("application/pdf");
                intentm.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, dateiname1);
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intentm);//New without request code

_________________________________________________________________________________________

 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override

                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
//                    Uri uri=null;
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getResultCode() == WRITE_REQ) {

                        if(result.getData() != null) {

                            Uri uri=null;
                          uri = result.getData().getData();
                 String   PfadNeu = uri.toString();



                                
                                    createDocument(uri);
                                
                                   

                            }
                        }


                 }


                }
            });

__________________________________________________________________________________________

private void createDocument(Uri uri) {

// create a new document

.....
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(500, 700, 1).create();

        // start a page

        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

 canvas.drawText(euroj, 283, 320, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurof, 283, 335, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euromaer, 283, 350, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euroa, 283, 365, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euromai, 283, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurojun, 283, 395, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurojul, 283, 410, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euroaug, 283, 425, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurosep, 283, 440, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurookt, 283, 455, paint);
        canvas.drawText(euronov, 283, 470, paint);
        canvas.drawText(eurodez, 283, 485, paint);
        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);



        try {

            ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            document.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            Toast.makeText(WeitereTools.this,"PDF - Datei wurde erstellt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        document.close();

}
```

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace(); to the catch block to see the error in logcat

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064340/how-to-save-tempfile-to-external-storage-using-action-open-document-tree

Comment: startActivityForResult is depresated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
Used a try - catch block when calling "createDocument".
The function is now called correctly. PDF is created.

```
                    try {
                            createDocument(uri);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
```